# Inserting into a column in file

Tags: shell

I have two files and first one is comma separated file with 6 columns and 3rd column is empty in it. 2nd file is a list of urls.

How would i insert all values from 2nd file in 3rd column of first file ?

Content of first file
Ex :

```
apple,fruits,,healthy,240
grapes,fruits,,healthy,80
Noodles,junk,,unhealthy,80
```

Content of 2nd file:

```
httpsxhhscom
httpseightcom
httpsxyzjcom
```

Each files have same number of records and need to be mapped one to one while inserting.ex:  1st row in 2nd file goes 3rd column of 1st file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `awk` simply by reading the second file into an index array and then updating the 3rd field in file1. For example:

```sh
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'FNR==NR {a[++n]=$1; next} m<=n {$3=a[++m]}1' file2 file1
```

**Explanation**

- the option `-F,` sets the field separator variable (`FS`) to `","`,
- the option `-v OFS=","` sets the output field separator variable (`OFS`) to `","`,
- `FNR == NR` (first rule condition) - the file record number (`FNR` - line number per-file) is equal to the total number of records processed (`NR`) -- only true for the first file processed by `awk`. `FNR` is reset to `1` for each file read, `NR` continues to increment.
- If conditon is true, store the url from the first file processed (`file2`) in the indexed array `a[]` with indexes `1, 2, 3, ...`. `next` skips to the next record (line) at that point.
- `m <= n` second rule condition - this will only be reached when processing the second file (`file1`). The 3rd field is updaded to the url stored in array `a[]` in order until the end of the second file or when `m > n` (if there are more records in the second file than the first)
- **Note:** `m` and `n` are simple variables used as counters for the array index. In `awk` when a variable is encountered before it is initialized or assigned a value, it's value is `0`, so `++n` simple sets `n = 1` the first time it is used. When `m <= n` is encountered before `m` has been incremented, it's value is `0`.
- `1` at the end is just shorthand for the default operation `print`.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file1` and `file2`, you would get:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS="," 'FNR==NR {a[++n]=$1; next} m<=n {$3=a[++m]}1' file2 file1
apple,fruits,httpsxhhscom,healthy,240
grapes,fruits,httpseightcom,healthy,80
Noodles,junk,httpsxyzjcom,unhealthy,80
```

To write that out to a file, simply redirect the result to a new file, e.g. `> newfile`.

Answer (score 0):

If file2 isn't gigantic, might as well pre-read it all :

```
mawk 'BEGIN {                                 RS="^$"
               getline <ARGV[++_]
     delete __[split ($(ARGV[_++-!++_]=""),__,RS="\n")] 
         FS = \
        OFS = "," } $_=__[NR]' testf2.txt testf1.txt

apple,fruits,httpsxhhscom,healthy,240
grapes,fruits,httpseightcom,healthy,80
Noodles,junk,httpsxyzjcom,unhealthy,80
```

Tested and confirmed working on `gawk 5.1.1`, `mawk 1.3.4`, `mawk 1.996`, and `macos nawk`

—- `The 4Chan Teller`